# Can I specify a different module for admin generator object_actions in Symfony 1.4

Tags: php, symfony-1.4

I'm using the admin generator in Symfony 1.4 and want to have a custom action.  I can specify `object_actions` in my generator.yml in which I can specify the action name, but is there any way to specify a different module name?

generator.yml

```
generator:
  class: sfDoctrineGenerator
  param:
    model_class:           MasterIndex
    theme:                 admin
    non_verbose_templates: true
    with_show:             false
    singular:              ~
    plural:                ~
    route_prefix:          master_index
    with_doctrine_route:   true
    actions_base_class:    sfActions

    config:
      actions: ~
      fields:  ~
      list:    
        actions: {}
        display: [=last_name, =first_name, =email, _number_poems, is_contestant, is_admin, is_disabled]
        object_actions: 
          payInvoice: {label: Enter Payment, action: payInvoice}  // how to specify a different module?
          _edit: ~
      filter:  
        display: [last_name, first_name, email, is_admin, is_contestant, is_disabled]
      form:    ~
      edit:    ~
      new:     ~
```

I've tried adding `module: payment` in the `payInvoice` key, but it has no effect.  Is this doable?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could add a brand new route (using a new module) in the routing file directly...

Comment: Ok - but how do I specify that route name from within the generator.yml file?

Comment: You could use an action in that module just to redirect it. I think that's hacky.